# Getting Instagram data from subscriptions

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have several Instagram subscriptions (geographies) made, several are in Manhattan and they are getting data.  I also put one at my exact location with a 5km radius.

However when I make posts i am not receiving the Instagram data.  I am also collecting tweet data and if I share the post on twitter I am only getting the tweet not the Instagram post.  The tweet is coming up as 300 feet from where i made the subscription.

On my Instagram post i have allowed locations and chose my exact location

How can i make an Instagram post be retrieved by my geography subscription?

How can i get the details of a subscription after the subscription is created (a lookup)?